# Tree plot displays in R, but not in R-Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am able to use the [data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/data.tree.pdf) package to produce a plot.  Here is an example of a plot:

```
library(data.tree)

org <- Node$new("Parent")
org$AddChild("Child_1")
org$AddChild("Child_2")

plot(org)
```

However, I am not able to render this plot in R-Shiny.  I have been able to render most other plots in Shiny.  What can I do to render this plot, and why is it not showing up?  Here is my Shiny code:

```
library(shiny); library(data.tree)

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(plotOutput("orgplot") )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  rv <- reactiveValues()

  org <- Node$new("Parent")
  org$AddChild("Child_1")
  org$AddChild("Child_2")

  output$orgplot <- renderPlot({ plot(org)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't think data.tree renders svg...which is what a plot is more or less...try `renderText` one the server and `verbatimTextOutput` on ui side and see if that works.

Comment: oh..and put all of the code in the render function body..and what's the point of rv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`plot(org)` generate widget of class `grViz` So you can use `renderGrViz` to show plot in shiny.

Like ( `textInput` used for example of change name of "parent")

```
  library(shiny); 
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(grVizOutput("xx")   ),
  textInput("parent","parent","parent")
)

server <- function(input, output){
output$xx=renderGrViz({
  org <- Node$new(input$parent)
  org$AddChild("Child_1")
  org$AddChild("Child_2")
  grViz(ToGraphViz(org),engine = "dot")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update add node dynamically**

If You want to add nodes dynamically you can try to add child to node by name( you need some checks to avoid names duplicate)

*New functions to draw chart get from @rpm answer*

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(uiOutput("add_child_ui"),
            grVizOutput("xx")   )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  #Create reative value to app
  vv=reactiveValues(org=NULL,names=NULL)

  #create main tree
  observe({
    vv$org <- Node$new("Parent1")
    vv$org$AddChildNode(child = Node$new("1"))
    vv$names=vv$org$Get('name') # get names of main tree
  })

  output$add_child_ui=renderUI({
    list(
    wellPanel(
      selectInput("Name_to_change","Name_to_change",vv$names),
      textInput("new_name","new_name",""),
      actionButton("Change_name","Change_name")
    ),
    wellPanel(
      selectInput("Parent_name","Parent_name",vv$names),
      textInput("new_node_name","new_node_name",""),
      actionButton("add_child","add_child")
    ))
  })
  observeEvent(input$Change_name,{

    aa=FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Name_to_change) 
    aa$name=input$new_name # Change name
    vv$names=vv$org$Get('name')# get names of new tree

    #re-generate chart
    output$xx=renderGrViz({

      grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_child,{

    FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Parent_name)$AddChildNode(Node$new(input$new_node_name)) # add child
    vv$names=vv$org$Get('name')# get names of new tree

    #re-generate chart
    output$xx=renderGrViz({

      grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
    })
  })

  output$xx=renderGrViz({

    grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: nice! didn't know about `renderGrViz`

Comment: @Batanichek, would it be possible to add an action button (or series of) that would dynamically generate children, siblings, etc?

Comment: @Batanichek That is seeming to work better. Would it be possible to have a textInput to change the initial name of the Parent and first child?

Comment: @Batanichek This seems to be getting the job done. If you wanted to remove a child, you should be able to mimic the observeEvent and $RemoveChildNode, correct?

Comment: @Batanichek, I added this to remove children, but I keep getting "attempt to apply non-function" error . Any ideas?     
    


    observeEvent(input$remove_child,{
    FindNode(node=vv$org,name = 
    input$Parent_name_to_remove)$RemoveChild(name = 
    input$Parent_name_to_remove)
    vv$names=vv$org$Get('name')

    
  
  output$xx=renderGrViz({grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine= "dot") }) })

Answer (score 3):

This code does not work as the ToGraphViz function has been retired from DiagrammeR and replaced with ToDiagrammerGraph. The following change works.

```
#  grViz(ToGraphViz(org),engine = "dot")
grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(org)))
```

Also, "parent" is a reserved word so I replaced it "parent2".