# Shiny: Dynamically Generate Data.Tree

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I am trying to create a dynamic shiny page to utilize the data.tree package but am having an issue when trying to add children and siblings dynamically through action buttons. I have provided a example but I can't get it to work right. It would be awesome if the list of children and siblings attached to the parent could be defined by the user.

```
library(shiny); 
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = (
      textInput("parent","parent","parent"),
      actionButton("add_child", "Add Child"),
      actionButton("add_sibling", "Add Sibling")  
    )

  )
  mainPanel(grVizOutput("HTATree")   ),
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$HTATree=renderGrViz({
    org <- Node$new(input$parent)
    child1 = org$AddChild("Child_1")
    child2 = org$AddChild("Child_2")
    child1$AddSibling("Sibling")
    grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(org)))
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_child,{
              #add a child under the parent   
               }
               )
  observeEvent(input$add_sibling,{
              #Add sibling
  }
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: see my example, its what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39703410/5018792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  i told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39703410/5018792) you can add panell to control your tree.

For example you have base tree:

```
#create main tree
vv$org <- Node$new(input$root_name)
vv$org$AddChildNode(child = Node$new(input[["1_child"]]))
vv$names=vv$org$Get('name') # get names of main tree
```

And 2 actions

1) Add

View:

```
column(4,selectInput("Parent_name","Parent_name",vv$names),
             textInput("new_node_name","new_node_name",""),
             actionButton("add_child","add_child"))
```

Listener:

```
observeEvent(input$add_child,{

    FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Parent_name)$AddChildNode(Node$new(input$new_node_name)) # add child
    vv$names=vv$org$Get('name')# get names of new tree

    #re-generate chart
    output$xx=renderGrViz({

      grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
    })
  })
```

2) Remove

View:

```
column(4,selectInput("Parent_name_remove","Parent_name_remove",vv$names),
             selectInput("Name_to_remove","Name_to_remove",""),
             actionButton("remove_child","remove_child"))
```

Listener1 to find child of selected node:

```
observeEvent({
   list(input$Parent_name_remove,
    input$add_child ,
    input$remove_child)},{
      if(!is.null(input[["Parent_name_remove"]])){
        node_=FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Parent_name_remove)
        children_names=node_$Get('name')
        updateSelectInput(session,inputId ="Name_to_remove",choices =  children_names[children_names!=input$Parent_name_remove] )

      }
     })
```

Listener2 to remove child:

```
observeEvent(input$remove_child,{
    if(input$Name_to_remove!=""){
      FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Parent_name_remove)$RemoveChild(input$Name_to_remove)
      #re-generate chart
      output$xx=renderGrViz({

        grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
      })
    }
  })
```

Full code

```
library(shiny); 
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(id="start",
        textInput("root_name","root_name","1"),
        textInput("1_child","1_child","1.1"),
        actionButton("go","go")
        ),
    uiOutput("add_child_ui"),
            grVizOutput("xx")   )
)

server <- function(input, output,session){


  #Create reative value to app
  vv=reactiveValues(org=NULL,names=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$go,{


    #create main tree
    vv$org <- Node$new(input$root_name)
    vv$org$AddChildNode(child = Node$new(input[["1_child"]]))
    vv$names=vv$org$Get('name') # get names of main tree

    output$xx=renderGrViz({

      grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
    })

    shinyjs::hide(id ="start" )

    output$add_child_ui=renderUI({
      fluidRow(
        column(4,selectInput("Parent_name","Parent_name",vv$names),
               textInput("new_node_name","new_node_name",""),
               actionButton("add_child","add_child")),

        column(4,selectInput("Parent_name_remove","Parent_name_remove",vv$names),
               selectInput("Name_to_remove","Name_to_remove",""),
               actionButton("remove_child","remove_child"))
      )

    })


  })










  observeEvent({
    list(input$Parent_name_remove,
         input$add_child ,
         input$remove_child)},{
           if(!is.null(input[["Parent_name_remove"]])){
             node_=FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Parent_name_remove)
             children_names=node_$Get('name')
             updateSelectInput(session,inputId ="Name_to_remove",choices =  children_names[children_names!=input$Parent_name_remove] )

           }
         })
  observeEvent(input$remove_child,{
    if(input$Name_to_remove!=""){
      FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Parent_name_remove)$RemoveChild(input$Name_to_remove)
      vv$names=vv$org$Get('name')# get names of new tree
      #re-generate chart
      output$xx=renderGrViz({

        grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
      })

    }
  })


  observeEvent(input$add_child,{

    FindNode(node=vv$org,name = input$Parent_name)$AddChildNode(Node$new(input$new_node_name)) # add child
    vv$names=vv$org$Get('name')# get names of new tree

    #re-generate chart
    output$xx=renderGrViz({

      grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(vv$org)),engine = "dot")
    })
  })



}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

well it's not pretty and kind of cludgey, but it works. A couple notes, in order to make siblings you will have to first use the traverse option to climb to that node as you cant make siblings at root :

```
library(shiny) 
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("mainpage")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  working <- reactiveValues(org = NULL)
  current <- reactiveValues(ch_name = NULL,prefix  =     NULL,addchild=NULL,addsibling=NULL)
  output$mainpage <- renderUI({
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fixedRow(
          textInput("parent","name of parent")
        ),
        fixedRow(
          textInput("initch_name","first child node name")
        ),
        fixedRow(
          h5("Must assign parent with initial child node")
        ),
        fixedRow(
          actionButton("crt_parent","Create Parent")
        ),
        fixedRow(
          if(!is.null(working$org)){
            selectInput("ttl","traverse to level",choices=c("root",if(!is.null(current$ch_names)){current$ch_names}))
          }
        ),
        fixedRow(
          textInput("ch_name","Child node name")
        ),
        fixedRow(
           actionButton("add_child", "Add Child")
        ),
         fixedRow(
          textInput("sib_name","sibling node name")
         ),
        fixedRow(
          actionButton("add_sibling", "Add Sibling")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(grVizOutput("HTATree")   )
    )
  })
  output$HTATree=renderGrViz({
     working$org 
      if(!is.null(working$org)){
        if(!is.null(current$addchild)){
        working$org$AddChild(current$addchild)
          current$ch_names <- names(working$org$children)
          current$addchild <- NULL}
        if(!is.null(current$addsibling)){
          working$org$Climb(input$ttl)$AddSibling(current$addsibling)
          current$ch_names <- names(working$org$Climb(input$ttl)$children)
          current$addsibling <- NULL}
    #child2 = org$AddChild("Child_2")
    #child1$AddSibling("Sibling")
    grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(working$org)))
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$crt_parent,{
    working$org <- makeorg()
    print(current$prefix$children)
  })
  makeorg <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$parent)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    if(is.null(working$org)){
   org <- Node$new(input$parent)
   org$AddChild(input$initch_name)
   current$ch_names <- names(org$children)
   return(org)}else{
     return(working$org)
   }
  })
  observeEvent(input$add_child,{
    current$addchild <- input$ch_name
      })
  observeEvent(input$add_sibling,{
    current$addsibling <- input$sib_name
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

second revision. traversal of levels allows the adding of children and siblings on all levels. might still be a bit buggy.

```
library(shiny) 
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("mainpage")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  active <- reactiveValues(main = 'initpage')
  working <- reactiveValues(org = NULL)
  current <- reactiveValues(ch_name = NULL,prefix  = NULL,addchild=NULL,addsibling=NULL,trunk_nm = NULL)
  output$mainpage <- renderUI({
    uiOutput(active$main)
  })
  output$initpage <- renderUI({
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fixedRow(
          textInput("parent","name of parent")
        ),
        fixedRow(
          textInput("initch_name","first child node name")
        ),
        fixedRow(
          h5("Must assign parent with initial child node")
        ),
        fixedRow(
          actionButton("crt_parent","Create Parent")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
      )
    )
  })
output$info_panel <- renderUI({
  tagList(
    fixedRow(
    h3("you are here")
  ),
  fixedRow(
    column(h4(current$trunk_nm$name),
           width=4
           ),
    column(h4(current$trunk_nm$level),
           width=2
    ),
    column(textOutput('chi_data'),
           width=4
           )
  )
  )
})
output$chi_data <- renderText({
  chdata <- chi_cnt()
  chdata
})
chi_cnt <- eventReactive(current$ch_names,{
 ln <- length(current$trunk_nm$children)
  for(i in 1:ln){
    if(i == 1){
      chi_list <- current$trunk_nm$children[[i]]$name
    }else{
      chi_list <- c(chi_list,current$trunk_nm$children[[i]]$name)
    }
  }
  return(chi_list)
})
  output$corepage <- renderUI({
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        #textInput("tree_name","tree name"),
    uiOutput("info_panel"),
    fixedRow(
      if(!is.null(working$org)){
        selectInput("ttl","traverse to  level",choices=c(current$trunk_nm$name,chi_cnt()),selected = NULL)
      }
    ),
    fixedRow(
      actionButton("tverse","Climb to level")
    ),
    fixedRow(
      textInput("ch_name","Child node name")
    ),
    fixedRow(
      actionButton("add_child", "Add Child")
    ),
    fixedRow(
      textInput("sib_name","sibling node name")
    ),
    fixedRow(
      actionButton("add_sibling", "Add Sibling")
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(grVizOutput("HTATree")   )
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$tverse,{
    current$trunk_nm <- current$trunk_nm$Climb(name=input$ttl)
  })
  output$HTATree=renderGrViz({
   working$org 
  if(!is.null(working$org)){
    if(!is.null(current$addchild)){
    current$trunk_nm$AddChild(current$addchild)
      current$ch_names <- names(current$trunk_nm$children)
      current$addchild <- NULL}
    if(!is.null(current$addsibling)){
      current$trunk_nm$AddSibling(current$addsibling)

      current$ch_names <- names(current$trunk_nm$children)
      current$addsibling <- NULL}
#child2 = org$AddChild("Child_2")
#child1$AddSibling("Sibling")
    grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(working$org)))
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$crt_parent,{
    active$main <- 'corepage'
    working$org <- makeorg()
    current$trunk_nm <- working$org
  })
  makeorg <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$parent)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    if(is.null(working$org)){
   working$org <- Node$new(input$parent)
   working$org$AddChild(input$initch_name)
   current$ch_names <- names(working$org$children)
    return(working$org)}else{
     return(working$org)
   }
  })
  observeEvent(input$add_child,{
    current$addchild <- input$ch_name
      })
  observeEvent(input$add_sibling,{
        current$addsibling <- input$sib_name
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Phi. When I am trying to add childen or siblings, I am only seeing that this relates it directly to the root and am not able to replicate more than a single level (i.e. Creating 1.2.1 as a child to 1.2). Is that possible here?

Comment: ok i've changed quite a few things. i'll make an entire second set of code as the second revision..

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. When I try to add a child to a child, thus asking a third level to the hierarchy/tree, it is only adding it to the initial parent. Is this a limitation of the visualization package or a limitation of a tree builder in R?

Comment: because of the way i wrote the code, and there may be better ways of doing it, you have to traverse to the 'level' where you want to add the child or sibling. i'll think about other ways of doing this and come back